# Extending RadiobuttonList Control to incorporate an "Other" option in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, custom-controls, radiobuttonlist

I'm attempting to extend a .NET RadioButtonList control to automatically include a textbox for "other".  However, I can't seem to retrieve the value of the text box.  I've tried using and .NET Textbox as well as an HtmlInputText control, to no avail.  The value seems to be getting lost before I try to retrieve it.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class RadioButtonListExtended : RadioButtonList
{        
    public bool AddOther
    {
        get
        {
            object o = ViewState["AddOther"];
            if (o == null)
                return false;
            return bool.Parse(o.ToString());
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["AddOther"] = value.ToString();
        }
    }

    public string OtherTextValue
    {
        get
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
            return txtOther.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
            txtOther.Value = value.ToString();
        }
    }

    private HtmlInputText txtOther;

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        txtOther = new HtmlInputText();
        txtOther.ID = "txtOther";
        Controls.Add(txtOther);
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        EnsureChildControls();

        writer.WriteLine("<table class='radios'>");
        writer.WriteLine("<tr>");

        // Write all the radio buttons
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (AddOther && (i == this.Items.Count - 1))
                writer.WriteLine("<td class='fs_otherSelect'>");
            else
                writer.WriteLine("<td>");

            writer.WriteLine("<input "
                + "id='" + this.ClientID + "_" + i + "'"
                + " type='radio' "
                + "name='" + this.ClientID.Replace("_", "$") + "' "
                + "value='" + this.Items[i].Value + "' "
                + ((SelectedValue == this.Items[i].Value) ? "checked" : "")
                + ">");

            writer.WriteLine("<label " + "for='" + this.ClientID + "_" + i + "'>" + this.Items[i].Text + "</label>");

            writer.WriteLine("</td>");

        }

        if (AddOther)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("<tr class='fs_otherEntry'>");
            writer.WriteLine("<td colspan='" + ((Columns > 0) ? Columns : this.Items.Count) + "'>");
            txtOther.RenderControl(writer);
            writer.WriteLine("</td>");
            writer.WriteLine("</tr>");
        }

        writer.WriteLine("</tr>");
        writer.WriteLine("</table>");
        writer.WriteLine("</div>");
    }
```

Comment: "The value seems to be lost." Can you confirm that the value was once stored in anywhere, at all?

Comment: @AustinWBryan Good point.  I'm not sure that it ever was.